# What's the alternative to Akka Aggregator as it will be deprecated in 2.5

Tags: scala, akka, actor

In the Akka documentation [version 2.5-SNAPSHOT](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/contrib/aggregator.html), it says:

> Deprecation warning - Aggregator has been deprecated and is scheduled for removal in the next major version. Feel free to copy the source into your project or create a separate library outside of Akka.

But it doesn't say what will (if any) replace it.

So what alternatives are available to Akka Aggregator?

Comment: The alternative is to "copy the source into your project or create a separate library outside of Akka" as the deprecation says. If you disagree strongly, open a ticket about it and we can discuss there.

Answer (score 2):

To quote from the [issue](https://github.com/akka/akka/issues/22198) when it was removed:

> I'd vote for deprecating Aggregator and ReceivePipeline doesn't look very useful to me and would probably be better as samples to start from than part of the library.